# On Decompositions of Finite Group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Any finite non-cyclic abelian group $G$ can be written as product $HK$ of two proper subgroups. Here $HK=\{ hk\colon h\in H, k\in K\}$. A step further, if $G$ is a finite group such that the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ is proper subgroup of $G$, then $G$ has a decomposition $HK$ for some proper subgroups $H,K$, since

1. if $G/[G,G]$ is non-cyclic then  we can pull back the decomposition for $G/[G,G]$;
2. if $G/[G,G]$ is cyclic, then we have the decomposition $G=HK$ where $H=[G,G]$, and $K=\langle x\rangle$ is a subgroup such that $G/[G,G]=\langle x[G,G]\rangle$.

The question I would like to ask is the natural one:

**Q.** Does every finite group admits a decompositon $G=HK$ where $H,K$ are proper subgroups?

By initial observations, it is sufficient to visit the question for groups $G$ such that $[G,G]=G$ (such groups are called [perfect groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_group)

Comment: @Marshal, I believe it suffices to consider simple groups, since if $G/N = H/N K/N$ then $G=HK$. I believe simple groups do have this property.

Comment: @dtldarek: Marshal means "does every finite group that is not cyclic of prime power order have such a decomposition"

Comment: @Jack, dtldarek: non-cyclic groups of prime power order will have such decomposition- take a maximal subgroup (which should be of prime index), and take an element outside maximal subgroup, the subgroup generated by this element and the maximal subgroup will give a decomposition. Cyclic $p$-groups do not admit a decomposition.

Comment: I do not think that all simple groups admit a factorization as a product of proper subgroups. Small examples are misleading. I believe that J. Saxl has some results on this question.

Comment: @Geoff: I tried this on GAP, and couldn't find examples of order 60,120,180,168,360, and 240.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: thanks! http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=880974 shows that most groups of Lie type (other than classicals) are not factorizable

Comment: And actually there are small counterexamples too (bad coding on my part missed them the first time round, actually checked G2(5) before I found the error). L2(13) is not factorizable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it were really true that all finite groups (other than cyclic $p$-groups) possessed a factorization, then it would suffice to prove this for non-abelian simple groups: if $G/N = (H/N) (K/N)$ then $G=HK$. A quick check reveals that if $G$ is a finite group with a top composition factor of order less than $1000$, then $G$ can be factored as $G=HK$. However, $G=\operatorname{PSL}(2,13)$ has no such factorization: the only possibilities for $H,K$ by order considerations are a Borel subgroup and a non-split torus. However, their intersection is always of size 2, which is too large, $|HK| = |G|/2$.

There are large families where there are never factorizations: finite simple groups of exceptional Lie types $E_6$, $E_7$, $E_8$ or twisted types ${}^2G_2$, ${}^3D_4$, ${}^2F_4$, and ${}^2E_6$ are not factorizable. This is shown in Hering–Liebeck–Saxl (1987).

- Hering, Christoph; Liebeck, Martin W.; Saxl, Jan.
  “The factorizations of the finite exceptional groups of Lie type.”
  J. Algebra 106 (1987), no. 2, 517–527.
  MR[880974](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=880974)
  DOI:[10.1016/0021-8693(87)90013-5](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(87)90013-5)